# Storm reading files throws "Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded"

Tags: java, file, garbage-collection, apache-storm, java-io

I've been working on a Storm topology in which I read from a file in the `execute(tuple)` method and Java throws me a `Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.
The program works fine until it throws that error. I guess it is because of the too many calls on Garbage Collector (GC). The same code used once works perfect, the problem is the extreme concurrence of my Storm implementation.
I think that my program spends too much time on GC. The way I programmed it is creating a lot of readers for the same file and Bolt everytime it executes a tuple.

I was wondering if it is possible to read the file in the `prepare()` method, and then save it in a String array? If so, I ask, would it only create one reader and String array for one Bolt instance?

Here's a sample of my Bolt:

```
public static class FilterSomeBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
  OutputCollector _collector;

  public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
    _collector = collector;
  }

  public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
    String entr = tuple.getString(1);
    boolean flagRet=false;
    try {
      String fileName2 = (String)"file.csv";
      BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName2));
      // read and ignore the header if one exists
      String line2 =reader2.readLine();
      while(line2!= null) {
        if(line2.toLowerCase().contains("something") && line2.toLowerCase().contains(entr.substring(1, 8).toLowerCase())) {
          flagRet=true;
        }//end if
        line2 =reader2.readLine();
      }//end while
  }
}
```

I'm trying to understand these methods, and would appreciate the help. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your file reading logic is creating the issue. If the first line of file is not null then your while loop will run infinite number of times. Please update it following code snippet:

```
while((line2 =reader2.readLine())!= null){
    ....//do anything you want
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't put the update of line2, but it is there, I'll edit the question, the bucle finishes just right, the error is not there, thanks!

Comment: now the while is like the one I have, I was cutting some code that I now it's not causing the issue and I missed the "line2" variable update, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Helped because I missed to post the "line2" updating on the question, but it is not the solution hence my code actually has that update of the line in it. I appreciate the help, but the question still remains, so I upvoted your answer, but I can't accept it as correct because you helped in the question posting, but not in the programming issue, to accept a question, it must solve the programming issue.
 Thanks for your help realising that I forgot the line2 update on the post, anyways :)

Comment: @Amnor Are you modifying line2 variable after reading inside whileloop in the part : "//some other non important code ..". Could you please check.

Comment: I just read it, the problem is not in that bucle, If you use Storm, you will realise that I would have noticed it. The program works fine until it throws that error, because of the too much use of the GarbageCollector. The same code used once works perfect, the problem is the extreme concurrence of my Storm implementation, hence a bolt replicates himself along the virtual machines. The problem is, that I'm not sure how to avoid the Storm topology to replicate the reader everytime i execute a tuple event, that's why I ask if it's possilbe to do that in the prepare() method :)

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that, you are helping me to make my question clearer, thanks for that! As I said, it works fine stand alone; the problem in the code comes with the parallelization via Storm. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129619/discussion-between-sachinsarawgi-and-amnor).